# Jquery count up and down in steps

Tags: jquery, count

I made a little script that gets a value from a selectbox. The selectbox value can be changed with plus and minus arrows.

I'm trying to increase that value with 4 or 6 but that gives me a wrong value over and over again.

So in short: I want the value inside  increased by 4 or 6 or decreased by 4 or 6.

HTML

```
<div class="quantity">
  <input type="text" name="quantity" value="{{ product.quantity }}" />
    <div class="change">
      <a href="javascript:;" onclick="updateQuantity('up');" class="up">+</a>
      <a href="javascript:;" onclick="updateQuantity('down');" class="down">-</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

JQUERY

```
 function updateQuantity(way){

  if(6 == 4){ //6 is a Twig tag and works. This is the only way to test if it's 4 or 6
    var qty = '4';
  }else {
    var qty = '6';
  }

    var quantity = parseInt($('.quantity input').val());

    if (way == 'up'){
        if (quantity < 100){
            quantity+qty; // gives me something like 444 or 666
        } else {
            quantity = 100;
        }
    } else {
        if (quantity > 6){
            quantity-qty; // actually works
        } else {
            quantity = 6;
        }
    }

    $('.quantity input').val(quantity);
}
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I really can't see it anymore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`qty` is a string and `+` will concatenates string.

Use `qty = 4` instead of `qty = '4'`

also use the following statements:

```
quantity+=qty;  // instead of quantity+qty
```

and

```
quantity-=qty;  // instead of quantity-qty
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey friend 6 0r 4 you have not mentioned anywhere but see my fiddle link might help you. I have added inputs that increases by 4 and decreases by 4.

here it goes

```
`http://jsfiddle.net/19c2uanm/`
```

Answer (score 1):

Within  single quotes the values are treated as strings .

So the values are concatenated (ie) 666 or 444.
use without single quotes ,so it may be considered as numeric addition.
[String usage in js](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_strings.asp)